# How do i make a list that gets added phone numbers everytime i enter a number and press submit in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

How to create an empty list that when someone enters a phone number in the phone number field and presses the Add button i created, adds that phone number to the list?

Comment: Your post needs a whole lot more detail. Shono 1's answer correctly specifies how to add values to a list. If the basics of lists is not your issue, what is? What have you tried? Where's your code?

Answer (score 1):

To create the list, use public member:

```
ArrayList<Integer> phone_numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

To add the number to the list, use:

```
phone_numbers.add(<input field get number>);
```

Place the code directly above in the event handler for your button press.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a way to implement a listener on the add button which would add the entered number into the list. Or are you trying to initialise a list and add a number to it from the listener which is not working.

If you are looking for a way to simply add an item to a list, the answer by @Shono 1 should work.

If you are looking for a listener, then you could do something like this in Kotlin:

```
// Initialise the empty array
val phoneNumbers = ArrayList<Integer>()

override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        // ...
        phoneNumberTextView.setOnClickListener {
                // Make sure your textView has an inputType set to just accept numbers
                // If not, perform an extra check to make sure the input text can be casted to an Integer
                val phoneNumber = phoneNumberTextView.text?.toInt() ?: 0
                phoneNumbers.add(phoneNumber)
              }
```

A little more explanation on what you've done so far and what issue you are facing is required.